# How to set value to the property that does not exist by creating new property in Javascript object?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have Javascript object as follows.

```
var data = {
      USER_LIKES: 
       { userId1: 
          { publishedContentId: 1492688420796,
            publishedContentId1: 'TIMESTAMP',
            publishedContentId2: 1492688750874 },
         userId2: 
          { publishedContentId: 1492688611936,
            publishedContentId1: 1492688730807,
            publishedContentId2: 'TIMESTAMP' } 
       }
    }
```

I can add more contents under existing userIds as follows.

```
data["USER_LIKES"]["userId1"]["publishedContentId3"] = admin.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP;
```

But I want to add contents under userId that does not exist in the object. For example I want to add content under userId3(not exist).

I have tried to do the same thing as follows

```
data["USER_LIKES"]["userId3"]["publishedContentId3"] = admin.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP;
```

but returns error `TypeError: Cannot set property 'publishedContentId1' of undefined`.

So how can I achieve this?

Comment: You should test for the existance of each object before trying to create something at a lower level.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Error message is quite verbose, You need to create `userId3` property first

```
data["USER_LIKES"]["userId3"] = data["USER_LIKES"]["userId3"] || {};
data["USER_LIKES"]["userId3"]["publishedContentId3"] = admin.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP
```

*OR*

```
data["USER_LIKES"]["userId3"] = {
   publishedContentId3 : admin.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP
};
```

Comment: @isuru, If you're applying multiple `publishedContent` properties as per the other objects in your post, you can also add them all together within the `{}` in the second option in this answer.